# How to properly use binascii.crc32 on a byte array

Tags: python, python-3.x, crc32

I have what should be an array of Hex but always seen as a 'str' by binascii.crc32().
As an exemple : `data =  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'].`

This is for frame building in order to put it in a txt file openable by Wireshark under specific format (not the problem here, this works fine).

As shown in documentation :
`print(binascii.crc32(b"hello world"))` works.

I tried to convert data into binary with bin() which gave me

```py
data = ['10101010', '10111011', '11001100']
```

However it is never seen as binary.

I tried to convert it using bytes() method but only managed to convert it into ASCII again.

```py
def toBin(data):
    data2=[]
    for iBcl in range (1,len(data)):
        if iBcl%2!=0:
            binary=bin(int(data[iBcl-1]+data[iBcl],16))[2:]
            data2.append(binary)
    print(data2)
    return data2

data="aabbcc"
data2=toBin(data)
print(binascii.crc32(data2[0]+data2[1]+data2[2]))
```

According to online CRC32 calculator the result should be
`0xBE4DF84C` but i've got the following error :
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

I don't get the error using bytes() method but CRC32 is then calculated on ASCII character and this give me incorrect crc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of hexadecimal data. You can convert each byte with `binascii.unhexlify` and then join all:

```
b = b''.join((binascii.unhexlify(i) for i in data))
print(b)
```

gives as expected

```
b'\xaa\xbb\xcc'
```

You can control the crc32:

```
print(hex(binascii.crc32(b)))
```

which gives:

```
0xbe4df84c
```